# White space around image issue

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whitespace around Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190108/whitespace-around-image)

Can't figure out how I"m getting this extra white space around my image:

[image]

**The markup:**

```
   <div id="searchCriteria-Wrapper">
        <p>@Html.Label("Contract #: ")</p><p> @Html.TextBox("searchCriteria")</p><p><input type="button" id="searchButton" title="Submit" value="Search" /></p>
    </div>
```

**the styles:**

```
input, textarea 
{
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px 2px 5px 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

img 
{
    display: block; /* gets rid off any unexpected margins round the image */
    border: 0px;
}


input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button 
{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: 600;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0px;
}

td input[type="submit"], td input[type="button"], td button { font-size: 1em; }
```

Comment: Could you pleease add more HTML markup because out of what you have provided, there is now way to check the code behaviour? My guess though is that the button having auto width is expanding by the padding stated in input, textarea...

Comment: Where is your image? Give the detail.