# Whitespace around Image

Tags: css

Can't figure out how I"m getting this extra white space around my image:

[image]

**The markup:**

```
       <div id="member-name"  hidden="true">
            <button type="submit" id="btnExpandSection"><img src="~/Content/Images/plus.jpg" /></button><p id="member-fullName"></p> 
        </div>
```

**the styles:**

```
   input, textarea 
    {
        border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
        background: #fff;
        color: #333;
        font-size: .9em;
        margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
        padding: 5px 2px 5px 5px;
        width: 300px;
    }

    img 
    {
        display: block; /* gets rid off any unexpected margins round the image */
        border: 0px;
    }


    input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button 
    {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: 600;
            width: auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
        border: 0px;
    }

    td input[type="submit"], td input[type="button"], td button { font-size: 1em; }
```

UPDATE:

There's also this style in there:

```
#member-name 
{
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
    background-color: #d28105;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
}


#member-fullName { margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;}
#member-fullName p{ display: inline;float: left;overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: no it's not live nor can I expose it to the net.

Comment: Padding is causing the whitespace.

Comment: And where is the CSS styling for `#member-name` and `#member-fullName`?

Comment: @sparky, check the update, I added those now so you can see those styles

Comment: I fixed it and will update this with my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just provide the image as a background to the button element?

```
#btnExpandSection {
    background: #ffffff url('/Content/Images/plus.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    height: /* image height */;
    width: /* image width */;
}
```

Comment: however yours is gonna use that across the board...I don't want that.  Only on this button.

Comment: if that's the case, then just use the button ID on the css. Updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this, and build it back from here...

```css
button,
#member-fullName,
#member-name,
#btnExpandSection,
#btnExpandSection img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But the following would definitely be preferably to an image nested between `<button></button>` tags.  Replace `32px` with actual width and height values of your image.

```css
button {
    background-image: url(~/Content/Images/plus.jpg);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px; 
}
```

Comment: I changed my markup to  <button type="submit" id="btnExpandSection" /><p id="member-fullName"></p> and then changed my style to #btnExpandSection button {
    background-image: url(~/Content/Images/plus.jpg);
    width: 21px;
    height: 18px; 
} now I don't even see the image and the person's name that I inject in that second <p> has white all around it...

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, firstly my code was not meant to replace _all_ of your CSS; it's a supplement to your existing CSS.  Secondly, can you setup a jsFiddle demo of this problem?